# highcharts download not working from html page with iframe in IE

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to get the chart download to work in IE9 from an html file having  just the 
iframe element as shown below .

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="500" height="425" scrolling="no" src="http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic"></iframe>
```

However it works fine if the iframe is placed inside a jsfiddle .I get the impression that 
this is due to some html elements missing in the html file .Please help me out on this issue.

Thanks,

Bimal

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this line in IE9 and it seems to be working fine.  Are you on a server or just opening an HTML file with the broswer?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue by setting up the highcharts export server in my .Net web app .